# Drupal translation javascript function Drupal.t does not work

Tags: javascript, drupal, locale, translation, translate

I have a custom trad file *.po

- mybestmodule.info.yml

```
interface translation project: mybestmodule
interface translation server pattern: modules/mybestmodule/translations/mybestmodule.%language.po
```

- translations/mybestmodule.fr.po

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: mybestmodule(1.0.0)\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2024-01-03 09:50+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2024-01-03 09:50+0200\n"
"Language-Team: French\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n!=1);\n"

msgid "mybestmodule.greeting"
msgstr "salut"
```

When I do the translation on the controller side via the `$this->t('mybestmodule.greeting')` or `t('mybestmodule.greeting')` function.

**=> it works correctly**.

the same, at the branch level, if I do `{{ 'mybestmodule.greeting'|t }}` or `{{ 'mybestmodule.greeting'|trans }}`

**=> it works very well**.

on the other hand, when I use it at the javascript level in
library with dependencies : `core/drupal`, `core/drupalSettings`, `core/once`, `core/jquery`

```
(function ($, Drupal, once) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myBestModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      once('myBestModule', 'body', context).forEach(function () {
        console.log(Drupal.t('mybestmodule.greeting'));
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal, once);
```

**=> it does not work**. it does not translate the word (returns `mybestmodule.greeting`). and when I check in the global js variable of `window.drupalTranslations` , there is a list but the word is not there.

I can see the word clearly from the translation BO `/admin/config/regional/translate`

I did several times `drush locale-check && drush locale-update && drush cr`

but yet it doesn't work; and that only on the JS part.

Any ideas?

THANKS

Comment: You mention that 'window.drupalTranslations , it is not there.' that is your first clue, you should first checky why not, are the libraries properly attached, is the language enabled, are you on a translated page (like site.com/en/node/1) if you're on a view or node page that has no language set, it can be that it wont understand with language set it has to use.

Comment: yes i am on a translated page. i mean window.drupalTranslations contains a list of translated strings, but not my custom word

Comment: Just to confirm, when you use t('mybestmodule.greeting') on a page generated via a controller, the variable is also not available in the window.drupalTranslations on that page?

Comment: I just checked, it's not there